# How to self-define the gradient of sign function in Keras or Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gradient, gradient-descent

I have a neural network, which accept the input I and output a real vector W. For some particular situation, I need to add a sign function to W and then put it into to loss function to compute my loss. Namely:

```
W = NN(I);   #the output of the neural network
W = sign(W); #can be realized by the Lambda layer in keras
loss = loss_func(W) #compute the loss with the result after sign function
```

Yes, it is really strange but necessary in my work. In my previous work without the sign function, it works well. However, when I add the sign function, I found that the program can run, but the loss can not decrease, and I think it is because the gradient of sign(W) is zero, which leads to the problem.

So I want to use some alternative smooth function whose gradient is not zero to instead sign function so that my loss can continue to be reduced. Is there any appropriate functions? and is there any effective way to self-define the gradient in Keras, or tensorflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about tanh function?

Comment: I　think it is a good choice, but can the function curve be more steep?

Comment: Yes, you can control the steepness by using `tanh(ax)`, higher the `a` more the steep

Comment: Thank you, I think it's a good solution

Comment: I'll add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

`tanh(ax)` function would be an approximate, smooth and differentiable function, you can control the steepness by controlling `a`, higher the `a` more the steep

Comment: Thank you! This was pretty helpful for me!